# Get position of canvas child element after drag.

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a `Canvas` with several children, and each children has a `MouseDragElementBehavior` attached. Something like this:

```
MouseDragElementBehavior drag = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
drag.Attach(ellipse);
```

I want to drag a child and get the new position of that child after the dragging, so i did something like this:

```
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
double top  = Canvas.GetTop(ellipse);
```

The problem is that i always get the same values for top and left after dragging as if the element was never dragged. 
How can i get the new position of the element?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any useful documentation on how this Behavior actually works, but I'd guess that it "moves" the control by setting the Margin, rather than the Canvas.Left/.Top. Have you checked the Margins to see if they are changing? Setting the Margin would be much more useful as it would extend compatibility to containers other than Canvas (such as Grid or StackPanel).

Comment: @JDB, no margins are intact. If parent element is `Canvas` then margins are aways `0,0,0,0`, when parent element is regular `Grid` then margin would always stay at initial location of the element, eg. `Margins: 102.929,85.605,0,0` ... this `MouseDragElementBehaviour` is very confusing..

Comment: @DimitryK - Cool. Perhaps you could post any useful information you've found as a separate answer so that it can be recognized and upvoted.